# Hybris redeclare relation

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to create a relation between Product2Componen

```
<relation code="Product2Components" localized="false" autocreate="true">
    <deployment table="ProdsCompRels" typecode="30008" />
    <sourceElement qualifier="product" type="Product" cardinality="one" collectiontype="list">
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
    </sourceElement>

    <targetElement qualifier="components" type="SimpleCMSComponent" cardinality="many">
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
    </targetElement>
</relation>
```

However , hybris OOTB has already a relation within product2ProductDetailComponent:

```
<relation code="ProductDetailComponentsForProduct" generate="true" localized="false" autocreate="true">
    <sourceElement qualifier="productDetailComponents" type="ProductDetailComponent" cardinality="many" collectiontype="list">
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
    </sourceElement>

    <targetElement qualifier="product" type="Product" cardinality="one">
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
    </targetElement>
</relation>
```

And when I compile it returns me this error because of this already existing relation that is completly useless to me:

```
Attribute CmsLinkComponent.product(Product):((cms2))::YAttributeDescriptor[cms2-items.xml:190(RelationTypeTagListener)][JALO] duplicates inherited attribute SimpleCMSComponent.product(Product):((puigcore))::YAttributeDescriptor[puigcore-items.xml:488(RelationTypeTagListener)][JALO]. Remove it or specify it as redeclared
```

How can I redeclare a relation ? Or what should I do here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the OOTB **ProductDetailComponent** extends **SimpleCMSComponent** and you want to use **SimpleCMSComponent** so I think you can simply use OOTB relation.

But if you really want to decare your own attribute/relation then you have to provide a different qualifier other than "product", as the product qualifier is already been used in the OOTB relation `ProductDetailComponentsForProduct`, where ProductDetailComponent is the subtype of SimpleCMSComponent.

```
<relation code="Product2Components" localized="false" autocreate="true">
    <deployment table="ProdsCompRels" typecode="30008" />
    <sourceElement qualifier="productRef" type="Product" cardinality="one" collectiontype="list">
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
    </sourceElement>

    <targetElement qualifier="components" type="SimpleCMSComponent" cardinality="many">
        <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
    </targetElement>
</relation>
```

Comment: That should not be a problem. Both, `User2ContactInfos` and `User2Carts` relations have the qualifier `user`

Comment: @FarrukhChishti  In your case, `ContactInfos` and `Carts` are different item type so it works. But in OP case, he is trying to declare the same qualifier "product" which already been declared in the sub itemtype (ProductDetailComponent) relation so you will get the error when you are trying to declare it again in the parent item type relation `duplicates inherited attribute SimpleCMSComponent.product(Product)`